# Вычисление конечной стоимости в зависимости от выбранных вариантов

Tags: javascript

Суть проблемы в следующем: имеется у нас страничка для продвижения товара, ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется JS код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var whole = 0;
    var top_cusel = 0;
    var top2_cusel = 0;
    var top3_cusel = 0;
    var top4_cusel = 0;
    var balance = $("#balance").html();
    balance = balance.replace(/[А-Яа-я]/g, "");
    balance = balance.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    balance = balance.replace(/\./g, "");
    $( "input" ).change(function() {
        whole = 0;
if ($("#check1").prop("checked") && $("#check2").prop("checked") && $("#check3").prop("checked")) {
            top4_cusel = $( "#day4-styler" ).find( ".jq-selectbox__select-text" ).html();
            top4_cusel = top4_cusel.replace(/[А-Яа-я]/g, "");
            top4_cusel = top4_cusel.replace(/\s+/g, "");
            top4_cusel = top4_cusel.replace(/\./g, "");
            if (top4_cusel == 1) {
                whole = {$setup.board_all_price};
            }
            else if (top4_cusel == 3) {
                whole = {$setup.board_all_price}*3;
            }
            else if (top4_cusel == 7) {
                whole = {$setup.board_all_price}*7;
            }
            else if (top4_cusel == 14) {
                whole = {$setup.board_all_price}*14;
            }
            else if (top4_cusel == 28) {
                whole = {$setup.board_all_price}*28;
            }
}
else{
        if ( $( "#check1" ).prop( "checked" ) ) {
            top_cusel = $( "#day1-styler" ).find( ".jq-selectbox__select-text" ).html();
            top_cusel = top_cusel.replace(/[А-Яа-я]/g, "");
            top_cusel = top_cusel.replace(/\s+/g, "");
            top_cusel = top_cusel.replace(/\./g, "");
            if (top_cusel == 1) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_up_price};
            }
            else if (top_cusel == 3) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_up_price}*3;
            } else if (top_cusel == 7) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_up_price}*7;
            } else if (top_cusel == 14) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_up_price}*14;
            } else if (top_cusel == 28) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_up_price}*28;
            }
        }

        if ( $( "#check2" ).prop( "checked" ) ) {
            top2_cusel = $( "#day2-styler" ).find( ".jq-selectbox__select-text" ).html();
            top2_cusel = top2_cusel.replace(/[А-Яа-я]/g, "");
            top2_cusel = top2_cusel.replace(/\s+/g, "");
            top2_cusel = top2_cusel.replace(/\./g, "");
            if (top2_cusel == 1) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_color_price};
            }
            else if (top2_cusel == 3) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_color_price}*3;
            } else if (top2_cusel == 7) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_color_price}*7;
            } else if (top2_cusel == 14) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_color_price}*14;
            } else if (top2_cusel == 28) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_color_price}*28;
            }
        }

        if ( $( "#check3" ).prop( "checked" ) ) {
            top3_cusel = $( "#day3-styler" ).find( ".jq-selectbox__select-text" ).html();
            top3_cusel = top3_cusel.replace(/[А-Яа-я]/g, "");
            top3_cusel = top3_cusel.replace(/\s+/g, "");
            top3_cusel = top3_cusel.replace(/\./g, "");
            if (top3_cusel == 1) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_vip_price};
            }
            else if (top3_cusel == 3) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_vip_price}*3;
            } else if (top3_cusel == 7) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_vip_price}*7;
            } else if (top3_cusel == 14) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_vip_price}*14;
            } else if (top3_cusel == 28) {
                whole = whole + {$setup.board_vip_price}*28;
            }
        }

        }

        $( "#whole_to_spayment" ).html(whole + " " + "р.");
        $( "#whole_to_spayment_val" ).val(whole + " " + "р.");
        if (whole > balance) {
            $("#oplata").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#alert-balance").css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $("#oplata").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#alert-balance").css('display', 'none');
        }


    }).change();        
});
```

Собственно проблема в том, что если мы выбираем различные дни, то конечная сумма у нас не меняется, пока снова не щелкнем чекбокс.

Comment: `$("input, select").change(function() { ...`

Comment: @Igor кошернее: `$('input, select').on( 'input', function() { ...`

Comment: Ни один из этих 2 вариантов не подходит. Если это $( "input" ).change(function() { заменить на один из ваших кодов, то будем наблюдать судорожное дёрганье всего блока, показанного на скриншоте.

Comment: А нельзя просто повесить onchange на select ??

Comment: @vitagame - Ваш `.change();` в конце вызовет анонимный обработчик столько раз, сколько элементов выбрано селектором (в показаном случае - 8 раз). Код в Вашем вопросе не может вызывать "судорожное дёрганье".

Comment: В другом проекте код аналогичный http://joxi.ru/nAy9n0McXMo34A и работает. В этом другой js плагин для селектов и не работает.

Comment: @vitagame - "По этим картинкам, по этим картинкам, которые мы рисовали для вас, Придумайте сами, придумайте сами, придумайте сами веселый рассказ."

Comment: В начале делаем так $( "input, select" ).change(function() и в конце убираем .change() и всё пашет.